# Split string by final space in R

Tags: regex, string, r, split, gsub

I have a vector a strings with a number of spaces in. I would like to split this into two vectors split by the final space. For example:

```
vec <- c('This is one', 'And another', 'And one more again')
```

Should become

```
vec1 = c('This is', 'And', 'And one more again')
vec2 = c('one', 'another', 'again')
```

Is there a quick and easy way to do this? I have done similar things before using gsub and regex, and have managed to get the second vector using the following

```
vec2 <- gsub(".* ", "", vec)
```

But can't work out how to get vec1.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `vec1 <- gsub(" [^ ]*$", "", vec)`?

Comment: This is brittle for strings with other whitespace (tabs, newlines) or only one word.

Comment: Thanks Frankie, but that only shows characters before the first space (in this case ("This", "And" and "And") rather than all characters before the second space

Comment: I updated the regular expression, try that one.

Comment: That does it thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is one way using a lookahead assertion:

```
do.call(rbind, strsplit(vec, ' (?=[^ ]+$)', perl=TRUE))
#      [,1]           [,2]     
# [1,] "This is"      "one"    
# [2,] "And"          "another"
# [3,] "And one more" "again"
```

Comment: Thanks Matthew, that works as does Frankies comment under my question

Comment: this is much better because I could use it inside the separate() function and it preserved the column values perfectly. Thanks