# Split string by last two characters in R? (/negative string indices)

Tags: r, dataframe, split

My data frame looks like:

```
b <- data.frame(height = c(190,165,174,176), name = c('John Smith 34','Mr.Turner 54', 'Antonio P. 23', 'John Brown 31'))

#   height          name
# 1    190 John Smith 34
# 2    165  Mr.Turner 54
# 3    174 Antonio P. 23
# 4    176 John Brown 31
```

As we can see name and age are the same value. So I want to split it by last two characters in string:

```
  height       name age
1    190 John Smith  34
2    165  Mr.Turner  54
3    174 Antonio P.  23
4    176 John Brown  31
```

How I can do that?

Comment: I would split on the last space, since age can have three digits sometimes.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19959697/split-string-by-final-space-in-r

Comment: `library(tidyr) ; b %>% separate(name, into = c('name', 'age'), sep = -3, convert = TRUE)`

Comment: or `b <- cbind(b[-2], setNames(as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(b$name), '.(?=..$)', perl = T)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE), c('name', 'age'))) ; b$age <- type.convert(b$age)`, but that's a lot more effort.

Comment: @alistaire, thank you a lot!

Comment: `cbind(b[1], read.csv(text = gsub(' (..)$', ',\\1', b$name), header = FALSE))`

Comment: In general, R doesn't support negative string indices, unlike Python. It really makes life easier though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`tidyr::separate` makes separating columns simple by allowing you to pass an integer index of split position, including negatively indexed from the end of the string. (Regex works as well, of course.)

```
library(tidyr)

b %>% separate(name, into = c('name', 'age'), sep = -4, convert = TRUE)
##   height        name age
## 1    190 John Smith   34
## 2    165  Mr.Turner   54
## 3    174 Antonio P.   23
## 4    176 John Brown   31
```

or separate by the final space:

```
b %>% separate(name, into = c('name', 'age'), sep = '\\s(?=\\S*?$)', convert = TRUE)
```

which returns the same thing.

In base R, it's a bit more work:

```
b$name <- as.character(b$name)
split_name <- strsplit(b$name, '\\s(?=\\S*?$)', perl = TRUE)
split_name <- do.call(rbind, split_name)
colnames(split_name) <- c('name', 'age')
b <- data.frame(b[-2], split_name, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
b$age <- type.convert(b$age)

b
##   height       name age
## 1    190 John Smith  34
## 2    165  Mr.Turner  54
## 3    174 Antonio P.  23
## 4    176 John Brown  31
```

Comment: Is there a way we can do that for a single observation? Actually, I have a column that contains Salaries in different currencies ie., ₹, $, £, and AFN. I can't separate the row which has AFN. It has now become 'FN', after the separation of 'A'. Any idea how to do that.

Comment: @classy_BLINK How complicated you need to get depends on what's possible in the data it needs to handle; any solution bakes in assumptions. One way to handle a lot may look like `x <- c('$120', '£ 100', 'AFN1,000'); strsplit(x, split = '(?<=[^\\d,])\\s*(?=[\\d,]+)', perl = TRUE)`; a simpler way would be `cur <- gsub('\\d|,|\\s', '', x); amt <- as.numeric(gsub('\\D', '', x))`.

Answer (score 3):

many options here using regular expression.I would use `substr` because you want know exactly the number of characters to extract.

Within `data.table` (for syntax-sugar):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(b)[,c("name","age"):=list(
  substr(name,1,nchar(name)-3),
  substr(name,nchar(name)-2,nchar(name)))]

   height       name age
1:    190 John Smith  34
2:    165  Mr.Turner  54
3:    174 Antonio P.  23
4:    176 John Brown  31
```

Note that *name* should be a `character`  :

```
  b <- data.frame(
  height = c(190,165,174,176), 
  name = c('John Smith 34','Mr.Turner 54', 'Antonio P. 23', 'John Brown 31'),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

With base R (the same data used in @agstudy's answer):

```
data.frame(t(apply(b,1,function(x) {s <- unlist(strsplit(trimws(x[2]), " "));
           c(x[1],paste0(head(s,-1),collapse=" "),tail(s,1)) })))

   # X1         X2 X3
# 1 190 John Smith 34
# 2 165  Mr.Turner 54
# 3 174 Antonio P. 23
# 4 176 John Brown 31
```

To be on the safe side, we split the *trimmed* `name` column by space (i.e. `strsplit(trimws(x[2]), " ")`) and take the last part (i.e. `tail(s,1)`) as `age` and the rest (i.e. `head(s,-1)`) as name.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would find the following regular expression most useful.

```
library (stringr)
b $age <- str_extract (b$name, "\\d{1,3}$")
b $name <- str_replace (b $name,  "\\d{1,3}$", "")
```

This looks for a sequence of digits 1-3 characters long at the end of the string. There is probably a way to incorporate it into the `separate` syntax, but I'm writing from my phone and cannot explore.

The advantage to this regular expression is it will handle single, double, and triple digit ages without having to depend on the space being present, or having to count back from the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

We can create a delimiter (`,`) instead of the space before the age using `sub`, read it with `read.table` and `cbind` with the first column using `base R`

```
cbind(b[1],read.table(text=sub("\\s+(\\d+)$", ", \\1", b$name), 
                 col.names = c("name", "age"), header=FALSE, sep=","))
#  height       name age
#1    190 John Smith  34
#2    165  Mr.Turner  54
#3    174 Antonio P.  23
#4    176 John Brown  31
```

---

Or using `extract` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
extract(b, name, into = c("name", "age"), "(.*)\\s+(\\S+)$")
#  height       name age
#1    190 John Smith  34
#2    165  Mr.Turner  54
#3    174 Antonio P.  23
#4    176 John Brown  31
```