# How to separate a dataframe based on specific string in column name

Tags: r

I have a huge data that I cannot split into two sets

```
    df<- structure(list(name = structure(1:3, .Label = c("a", "b", "c"
), class = "factor"), X3C_AALI_01A = c(651L, 2L, 1877L), X3C_AALJ_01B = c(419L, 
2L, 1825L), X3C_AALK_01A = c(1310L, 52L, 1286L), X4H_AAAK_11B = c(2978L, 
4L, 1389L), X5L_AAT0_01B = c(2576L, 15L, 1441L), X5L_AAT1_01A = c(2886L, 
5L, 921L), X5T_A9QA_03A = c(929L, 3L, 935L), A1_A0SI_10A = c(1578L, 
1L, 2217L), A1_A0SK_07C = c(3003L, 6L, 2984L), A1_A0SO_01A = c(6413L, 
0L, 3577L), A1_A0SP_05B = c(5157L, 5L, 4596L), A2_A04P_01A = c(4283L, 
6L, 2508L), X5L_AAh1_10A = c(2886L, 5L, 921L), X5T_A0QA_03A = c(929L, 
3L, 935L), A1_A0Sm_10A = c(1578L, 1L, 2217L), A1_ArSK_01A = c(3003L, 
6L, 2984L), A1_AfSO_01A = c(6413L, 0L, 3577L), A1_AuSP_05A = c(5157L, 
5L, 4596L), A2_Ap4P_11A = c(4283L, 6L, 2508L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

basically , I want to split the data based on the last character of the column name. for example if you look at the above data, the second column is like this 3C_AALI_01A which I want to generate two data sets based on the **_01A**

So those columns that have 01 to 09 values I want them to be in one data frame and those ones that have 10 to whatever number want them to be in the second data frame. For example in the above example data.

the columns with the following names should be in one data frame

```
3C_AALI_01A
3C_AALJ_01B
3C_AALK_01A
5L_AAT0_01B
5L_AAT1_01A
5T_A9QA_03A
A1_A0SK_07C
A1_A0SO_01A
A1_A0SP_05B
A2_A04P_01A
5T_A0QA_03A
A1_ArSK_01A
A1_AfSO_01A
A1_AuSP_05A
```

and the columns with the following names should be in another data frame

```
4H_AAAK_11B
A1_A0SI_10A
5L_AAh1_10A
A1_A0Sm_10A
A2_Ap4P_11A
```

Comment: Really you want negative string indexing. Also, your dataframe is kind of transposed, it would be more normal to have one single column name with the names, and numerical columns `a, b, c`. Like `t(df)` without the unwanted coercion to string. If your dataframe was structured like that, you could use `tidyr::separate(..., sep=-1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df1 <- df[,grep('0[1-9].$',colnames(df))]
df2 <- df[,-grep('0[1-9].$',colnames(df))]
```

Comment: Quotes in at least two of your answers are incorrect. Please edit.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Or edit and I will accept?

Comment: It was an issue with the keyboard on this device. Do they appear correct to you now?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`tidyr::separate(..., last=-1)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39811758/202229) approach

- which uses negative string indexing, which is what you really want here
- also, your dataframe is transposed, it would be more normal to have one single column `name` with the names, and numerical columns `a, b, c`. Like `t(df)` without the unwanted coercion to string.